# PHP - Is there a way to ignore fatal errors in php.ini/ini_settings only without modifying the code?

Tags: php

I inherited some PHP source code, and I have to maintain it. It has been built from scratch using no framework, just the former developer's own creation.

Now, I ask this:

**Is there a way to ignore fatal errors in php.ini/ini_settings only without modifying the code?**

Scenario:

SomeClass.php:

```
<?php class SomeClass {
...)?>
```

index.php:

```
include("SomeClass.php");
...
include("SomeClass.php");
```

In my development box, this throws a Fatal Error exception (because SomeClass has been declared twice), which is the obvious and expected behavior.

Here is the kicker: This source is hosted somewhere, **and it works.** I just don't ANY access to that server.

So I see here two scenarios:

1.) There is a way to silence this Fatal Error via 2 includes by an ini setting. This I have to know.

2.) The former developer did NOT give me the exact, updated source code that is currently up and running. I then have to insist that he give me the latest source code, but I can only do this if I am 100% sure that there is no way #1 can happen.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Honestly, that sounds like a nightmare scenario where much of your task depends on something you have no control over.  I'd either get my hands on that source or start looking elsewhere.

Comment: What can I say? Life. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried setting a `set_error_handler()` function that doesn't die on fatal errors, but instead Apache crashed. In other words, PHP **needs** to die so that the system doesn't.

So, sorry, I really don't think there is a solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

Fatal errors don't come from the include function - only warnings. You'd get fatals from require, though. Use @include and it won't even generate the warning.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but then I have to modify the source code, which then means that I did not receive the latest code from the former developer. What I'm really looking for is if there is a way (or not) to silence this using ini settings ONLY

Comment: Ah, I misinterpreted your post. You can set the error reporting level in php.ini - google "php error_reporting php.ini", but there's nothing you can do about FATAL errors flying out of this app. They can't (and should not) be suppressed.

Comment: that's what I'm thinking as well, but then again maybe I missed an ini setting that can suppress this Fatal Error...

Comment: Nope, you can't suppress them. Nothing will do it.

Answer (score 0):

inform your developer that he should use `__autoload` or `spl_autoload` to avoid such errors…

Answer (score 0):

Error reporting is mostly discouraged on production servers. Why let the user see if your script didn't find a file. Have a look at this http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php. The latter could be helpful, go through the page for examples. I suggest to log errors instead of displaying it. But that will involve some sort of workaround with code.